# Slack API Message formatting

Tags: post, format, chat, message, slack-api

I would like to pass such a message through slack chat post API which will follow this format:

*Attention* where Attention word will be printed as bold with two stars before and after. But as slack itself considering * for formatting a word bold so the before after stars are not printing.

My script

```
 $ch = curl_init("https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage");
            $data = http_build_query([
             "token" => "*******",
             "channel" => '#notifications-test',                
             "text" => '*Attention* `@channel` - Please inform the client. 75% of monthly hours have been used.'
            ]);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Please help

Answer (score 2):

Use `"mrkdwn": false` property. That would turn off auto formatting in Slack.